# Why SQL Server trigger does not fire after insert using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I have a C# application using Entity Framework and I created a trigger in the database to fire after insert and update.

I notice that the trigger does not fire when I insert or update using EF code, on the other side the trigger fires when I insert or update through SQL Server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[updateLoanFinishing] 
ON [dbo].[Installments_Paids] 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @totalLoan decimal, @totalpaid decimal, @balance decimal    

    SELECT @totalLoan = l.Total_Amount 
    FROM dbo.Loans l

    SELECT @totalpaid = ISNULL(SUM(ip.Paid_Amount), 0)  
    FROM dbo.Installments_Paids ip 

    SELECT @balance = @totalLoan - @totalpaid

    IF @balance = 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Loans
        SET dbo.Loans.IsFinish = 1 -- bit 
        FROM dbo.Loans l 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.Loan_ID =  l.Loan_ID 
    END
    ELSE IF @balance > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Loans
        SET dbo.Loans.IsFinish = 0 -- bit 
        FROM dbo.Loans l 
        INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.Loan_ID =  l.Loan_ID 
    END
END
```

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't have any magic that lets it bypass triggers. Try running SQL Profiler to see what commands are hitting the database.

Comment: Did you forget to `SaveChanges()` on your db context?

Comment: No i did't forget it

Comment: was there more than one entity that was changed? try to save changes with every entity individually

Comment: @ِAhmed did you find solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your trigger **is** being called - it's just flawed and cannot execute properly.

Have a look at it:

```
DECLARE @totalLoan decimal, @totalpaid decimal, @balance decimal    

SELECT @totalLoan = l.Total_Amount 
FROM dbo.Loans l
```

What are you trying to do here?? You have a **single variable** called `@TotalLoan` and you're assigning to it the whole `Loans` table, `Total_Amount` column? Is there only **one row** in that table?? Otherwise, this is **not** a valid assignment - you **cannot** assign a whole table to a single variable.....

Same goes for the next statement - again you're assigning basically a whole table to a single variable - that just **cannot** possibly work!

What are you **really** trying to do here?? You might need to add a `WHERE` clause to your statements, or did you plan to use `SUM(....)` for those assignment, or do something else to make them work - but I'm pretty sure this trigger **is** called, it just cannot do what you expect it to do since it's flawed